# How to show form errors on server-side validation?

Tags: materialize

I've used Bootstrap over years with Laravel. Now I want to use Materialize for a new project.

I need to validate the user input. With [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/forms/#server-side) you can use simply HTML to create form errors:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control @if($errors->has('city')) is-invalid @endif" name="city">
@if ($errors->has('city'))
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide a valid city.</div>
@endif
```

How can I create this *static* form errors with materialize?

Comment: Is this a question about how Laravel form validation errors are accessed, or a css question on how to translate bootstrap classes to another css framework?

Comment: it's a question on how to translate bootstrap classes to another css framework. I removed the laravel tag.